# Inverse Laplace transform of wave equation solution

Tags: taylor-expansion, laplace-transform

In a practice exam question, we are asked to find the Laplace transform solution of the 1D wave equation $\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2y}{\partial x^2}$ obeying certain boundary conditions. It is a show-that question, and I was able to obtain the correct solution:
$$Y(x,p)=\frac{a\sinh\left\lbrack\tfrac{p}{c}(L-x)\right\rbrack}{p\sinh(\tfrac{pL}{c})}.$$

The next part of the question is:

> By use of the binomial theorem or otherwise, express $y(x,t)$ as an infinite series.

I have tried Taylor expanding and using the formula $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+\dotsb$ (which I think is what they're hinting at with "binomial theorem") but to no avail...

Comment: boundary conditions? initial conditions?

Comment: The question is really about the inverse Laplace transform, which is why I left out the specifics of the DE. However, we have initial conditions $y(x,0)=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,0)=0$ and boundary conditions $y(0,t)=a;\,y(L,t)=0.$

Comment: You have poles which your contour integral has to go around. I don't really see immediately why the binomial theorem would be used here.